# Is it possible to tell clang which registers to use for certain parts of the code without using assembly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, x86-64, clang++

I'm working on an project that requires it to work on both Linux and Windows.
 However, there are portions of the code that don't work on Linux due to differing registers under `clang` and `msvc`.

Is there a way to either make the register use consistent or request that `clang` use a specific register during an operation? I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve rewriting portions in assembly. Here is what I'm talking about as differing output code.

https://godbolt.org/z/DO9pQN

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** per comments:
This is for an emulator so certain registers are used for certain tasks.
One of the main things is that we use RSI for a certain variable and then clang uses RSI in function calls. MSVC compiled does not suffer from the same problem.

**EDIT 2** per comments:
This is for the xbox 360 emulator, Xenia.
We are currently trying to finish the Linux side of things. However, we are running into problems with clang using the same registers for function calls as we use for storing something called a context.
Our idea was to just ask clang to not use that particular register, but I couldn't find a way to do that without just writing it in Assembly. Another problem with that solution is that `gcc` might also have the same issue on a different register. Specifically, we are looking at the ppc-tests. The above link is the output from clang compared with msvc.

Here is the relevant code:

- https://github.com/xenia-project/xenia/blob/e79e18bb271212b13bcb65a610d957b6058f34db/src/xenia/cpu/backend/x64/x64_backend.cc
- https://github.com/xenia-project/xenia/blob/master/src/xenia/cpu/ppc/testing/ppc_testing_main.cc

Comment: I'm confused; Why exactly does it matter which registers the compiler uses? Why doesn't it work on Linux when it uses other registers?

Comment: What are you doing that you care about what register the compiler uses?  Normally code shouldn't care about that sort of implementation detail.

Comment: This is clearly an implementation detail, and code developer shouldn't worry about it at all. As a result, this question seems to be about XY problem. Please explain what is the end goal.

Comment: You're right. I should have been more clear. This is for an emulator so certain registers have been set aside for certain tasks. The host is already set to expect the values in the registers msvc uses which isn't the same as what clang uses.

Comment: For me this looks like problem with ABI which defines how registries are used. This may be a problem when using library with different ABI without informing compiler about that. I'm suspecting simultaneous use of different compilers  (for example application build with VS library build with clang)  or  something like that. Since OP doesn't provide relevant information this is still clearly and [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) adn until information about `X` is provided there is no point in helping.

Comment: @MarekR what do you mean by simultaneous use? We use msvc on windows and clang on linux. We only use 1 compiler on each platform. GCC could be used on Linux but someone who came before me opted for clang.

Comment: @SergeyA the end goal is to get the Linux version of Xenia to work.

Comment: @ChristianHawley If I understudy correctly you have somewhere a border: emulator with is build with clang and something extra which is build with other compiler. When those two parts of code communicate they use different ABI and you have a problem.

Comment: @MarekR That's not accurate. It's compiled with the same compiler throughout the build process. Entirely msvc on windows and entirely clang on linux. On each platform, no previously compiled code is reused. That is, If I copy the Xenia folder to Linux and compile it there, it will not try to use the msvc compiled code.

Comment: You cannot use rsi on linux for your own purpose because rsi is used in the calling convention see: https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf. If you had chosen a temporary register like r10 you could compile with gcc `-ffixed-r10`, demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Sbpk_C

Comment: @Oliv that's what I was looking for. Thank you. If you put that as a post, i'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsi` cannot be used for your own purpose on linux because it is used in the function calling convention [psABI-x86_64](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)

But if you can use an other register as `r10` code compiled with Gcc and option `-ffixed-r10` will not use `r10` ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Sbpk_C)).